# Proving $\ln\left(\cos \frac{1}{2^n}\right) = O\left(\frac{1}{4^n}\right)$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, asymptotics

I would like to show that :

$$\ln\left(\cos \frac{1}{2^n}\right) =  O\left(\frac{1}{4^n}\right)$$

Attempt :

let's show that the limit :

$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty}  4^n\ln\left(\cos \frac{1}{2^n}\right)$ is bounded. Now the problem is that I need  to control at which speed $\ln(...)$ go to $0$. Yet I don't se how to do so.

Thank you !

Comment: $\cos x = 1- \frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^3)$ and $\ln(1+x) \simeq x$.

Comment: $\cos x$ goes to 1 for $x\to0$, so you need to know $\ln$ close to 1.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net we even have : $\cos x = 1 -\frac{x^2}{2} + O(x^2)$ which is better to use here I guess

Comment: @Thinking with a little o, else the $-x^2/2$ is absorbed by $O(x^2)$.

Comment: For technical reasons, posting titles that are all MathJax is discouraged - on default settings, it overrides the right-click menu that would be used to open the question in a new tab. I've edited a word into this one. In the future, please keep this in mind when posting questions.

Comment: @zwim The $O(x^3)$ is just more precise right ? I mean it's not false to say it's $O(x^2)$ since $x^3 = O(x^2)$.

Comment: The problem is $-\frac{x^2}2\in O(x^2)$ so you get only $\cos x=1+O(x^2)$ you lose your term in $x^2$. So you need at least $O(x^{2+\epsilon})$, thus $O(x^3)$ is the simplest choice. If you want to say anythng $\ll x^2$ then the little o notation is better $o(x^2)$.

Comment: Use L'Hostpital twice on the following function:
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\ln\left(\cos x\right)}{x^{2}}\stackrel{_{L'H}}{=}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\sin x}{2x\cos x}\stackrel{_{L'H}}{=}\lim_{x\to0}\frac{-\cos x}{2\cos x-2x\sin x}=-\frac{1}{2}$$
Now plug in $x=2^{-n}$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have $$\cos x=1-\frac{x^2}2+o(x^2)\\\cos\frac1{2^n}=?\\\ln (1-x)=x+o(x)\\\ln\left(\cos\frac1{2^n}\right)=?$$

Can you fill in the blanks?

Answer (score 0):

Consider that, for small $\epsilon$
$$\cos(\epsilon)=1-\frac{\epsilon ^2}{2}+\frac{\epsilon ^4}{24}+O\left(\epsilon ^6\right)$$
Continue with Taylor series to get
$$\log (\cos (\epsilon ))=-\frac{\epsilon ^2}{2}-\frac{\epsilon ^4}{12}+O\left(\epsilon ^5\right)$$ Make $\epsilon=\frac 1{2^n}$ and ... continue